# Wix 3.6 bootstrapper to just launch msi

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I am working with WIX 3.6, it has some great features to create managed bootstrapper application. I have managed to create a WPF ui for that. But, I dont want to create and handle all the events for the installer, our requirement is only to get an initial parameter like language selection from the user and proceed to the MSI. MSI already handles upgrade / uninstall and install checks.

Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);

Is it possible to just launch the MSI without specifying the install / uninstall action codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not today. The interface provided today is very powerful and you can control just about everything. That also means that you need to control a lot to get the core scenarios working. As we progress in the WiX toolset, we'll build up additional abstraction layers so that a custom BA is easier to write. The Burn functionality is still rather new and just needs time to have more code contributed.

If you want to look on the bright side, be glad that you'll be able to accomplish just about any required UI task because the interface provided is so expressive. :)

Comment: Hi Rob. I was afraid of that :) Thanks for your prompt reply. Its great though, we might end up having the slickest installer in the org. Cheers.